# I want to populate several text boxes using a number using javascript

Tags: javascript

On my web page I have few text boxes (numbers vary) staked vertically one above the other. The id of the first text box is `id="item1"`, the id of the next text box is `item2` and so on. 
I want to populate a number say 1 in every field and then remove it automatically. 
Can this be done my JavaScript ?? 
I don't know JavaScript, but I can install scripts using greasemonkey.
If anyone helps me out, I would be of great help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To populate the data:

```
for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    document.getElementById('item' + i).value = '1';
}
```

Where `n` is the number of your textboxes.

---

To remove the data:

```
for (var i = 1; i < n; i++)
{
    document.getElementById('item' + i).value = '';
}
```

Comment: Why did I get -1? Have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: should i install this code as a grease monkey script ?? how should i run it once the webpage with the text boxes has loaded ??? i dont want this to happen as soon as the page loads but I want to trigger it.

Comment: This is a standalone Javascript code. You should place it to the end of the HTML document. Unfortunately I don't know grease monkey.

Comment: You are welcome. If you don't have any other questions regarding this topic, please mark my answer accepted. Thank you